# Databable search all records on pagination

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have a datatable where I use Ajax and SQL to get the data from the database. I also created some search fields in order to search specific column in the database.

The datatable uses pagination and when searching the table, it only searches in the rows shown on the page. That is 10 records per page.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("example");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
```

php code

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
        0 =>'reservation_id',
    1 =>'unit_name',
    2 =>'checkin_agent',
    3 =>'quality_check_agent',
        4 =>'guest_full_name',
        5 =>'source',
        6 =>'no_guests',
        7 =>'checkin_date',
        8 =>'checkout_date',
        9 =>'entered',
        10 =>'checkin_time',
        11 =>'total',
        12 =>'complete',



);

    function getData($sql){
        global $conn ;//we use connection already opened
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) OR DIE ("Can't get Data from DB , check your SQL Query " );
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $row ) {
            $data[] = $row ;
        }
        return $data;
    }


// getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT reservation_id, unit_name, checkin_agent, quality_check_agent, guest_full_name, source, no_guests, DATE_FORMAT( checkin_date , '%e %b %y') as checkin, DATE_FORMAT( checkout_date , '%e %b %y') as checkout, DATE_FORMAT( entered , '%e %b %y') as entered, checkin_time, total, complete";
    $sql.=" FROM reservations2 INNER JOIN guest USING (guest_id) INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) ORDER BY checkin_date";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error, insert query failed with:' . $error);
$totalData = count(getData("SELECT * FROM reservations2 "));
$totalFiltered = count(getData("SELECT * FROM reservations2 ")); // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    // if there is a search parameter
    $sql = "SELECT reservation_id, unit_name, checkin_agent, quality_check_agent, guest_full_name, source, no_guests, DATE_FORMAT( checkin_date , '%e %b %y' ) as checkin, DATE_FORMAT( checkout_date , '%e %b %y') as checkout, DATE_FORMAT( entered , '%e %b %y') as entered, checkin_time, total, complete";

    $sql.=" FROM reservations2 INNER JOIN guest USING (guest_id) INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id)";
    $sql.=" WHERE total LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    // $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" OR total LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR total LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("get-table-data.php: get employees");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // modify total number filtered rows as per search result without limit in the query 
    $sql.=" LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; 
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error, insert query failed with:' . $error); 
} else {    
    $sql = "SELECT reservation_id, unit_name, checkin_agent, quality_check_agent, guest_full_name, source, no_guests, DATE_FORMAT( checkin_date , '%e %b %y' ) as checkin, DATE_FORMAT( checkout_date , '%e %b %y') as checkout, DATE_FORMAT( entered , '%e %b %y') as entered, checkin_time, total, complete";

    $sql.=" FROM reservations2 INNER JOIN guest USING (guest_id) INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) ORDER BY checkin_date";
    $sql.=" LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."    ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error, insert query failed with:' . $error);
}
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 
    $nestedData[] = $row["reservation_id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["unit_name"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["checkin_agent"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["quality_check_agent"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["guest_full_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["source"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["no_guests"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["checkin"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["checkout"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["entered"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["checkin_time"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["total"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["complete"];
    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you populate this table? Remember you can only use javascript here if you have all data on the client side. If you're going to use ajax you should made the search at the server side.

Comment: I added it to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using php you can follow this example:
[DataTable Server Side Example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)